# What does cardinality mean in 3GPP specifications?

Tags: 5g

What does cardinality mean in 3GPP specifications?

Example: 4th column of Table 5.1.6.2.2-1 in 3GPP TS 29.520 version 16.9.0 Release 16

Cardinality = 1..N, 0..1 etc.?

Comment: it means the allowed number range

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concept of cardinality in 3GPP standard is same as in dbms

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).